# Dynamic Label in Swift, doesn't Scroll

Tags: ios, swift

I'm Learning Swift, and I want to figure out how I can scroll the UILabel

I have a Label that is populated dynamically , But the text goes under the bottom bar.

[image]

I tried with 0 Lines, Constraints.. I'd like to scroll the view for read whole text

**UPDATE**

After the answers I have this situation

[image]

With Textview I Can read all my text, using the scroll
With UIScrollbar and UILabel, I can't read all my Text.

When I have to use TextView instead of UIScrollBar+UiLabel?

Comment: You should use UIScrollView if the content goes out of the screen.

Comment: @rakeshbs i'm trying, Do I have insert the label inside UIScroolView?

Comment: Add the label into a UIScrollView. set the content size according to the size of the label.

Comment: very better, Now i Can scroll, but i can't see whole text. It's truncate even if I choose Clip

Comment: I dont understand truncate? Did you extend the height of the label frame so that it will contain all the text without truncation?

Comment: I have the long text, and if I use UIScrollView + UILabel, I don't see whole text, even if i Scroll until the end. Instead I tried with TextView and I can see all my text...Why I have to use UIScrollView + UILabel Instead of textView? thanks

Comment: you can use a uiscrollview when you want all your content to scroll if you have more than one control. Otherwise textview will serve the purpose.

Comment: What are the benefits of placing a `UILabel` inside a `UIScrollView`, instead of just using `UITextView`? (can't think of any right now)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add the UILabel into a UIScrollView. Set the content size according to the size of the UILabel.

You can also use a scrollview, if you have more than one control to scroll together. For example you have an image on top and a description below and you want to scroll them together, you can use a UIScrollView. Just put the image view and UILabel inside the scrollview.

If its just text you want to scroll, you can use a UITextView.

Comment: thanks, but I don't understand why i Can't see all my text inside UIScrollView

Comment: You may just have to increase the height of the label and scrollview accordingly.

Comment: my UILabel is height like my UIScrollView

Comment: text is truncated because UILabel is not large enough.

Comment: but I don't know How much height have to be, because it's dynamically

Comment: You can call UIlabel sizeToFit programmatically. and set the frame of the label as content size of the uiscrollview.

Answer (score 24):

Alternatively, you can replace `UILabel` with `UITextView`.
Then set `textView.editable = false`.

Comment: Also add `textView.isSelectable = false`